# UIView extension in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift-extensions

I have placed a `UIView` `extension` in a utilities class written in swift.
However, when I try to call a method from the extension,

The **compiler** tells me the

> The member does not exist

Here is my extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        clipsToBounds = false
    }
}
```

Since `UIImage` subclasses `UIView`, I think I should be able to apply the method to a custom `MKAnnotation` image in a `UIViewController` by calling

```
myImage.addShadow()
```

However, I get error:

```
Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'addShadow'
```

If I place the method in an extension of UIImage, I get same error.

Do I have to tell the `UIViewController` about the utilities class somehow or what could be wrong with my code?

Comment: I suspect this is a syntax issue. You likely want a UIImage*VIEW*, but the error says UIImage.

Comment: You are right. Does an annotationview have an imageView or is it it's own imageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making an extension for `UIView`. Not `UIImageView`

```
extension UIImageView {

    func addShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        clipsToBounds = false
    }
}
```

**Also please use the `UIImageVIew` directly, not the `UIImage`**

## EDIT

Assuming by your comments, i think you're trying to modify an `MKAnnotationView`. If so here's a question that will help you.

[How to create rounded image with border and shadow as MKAnnotationView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270970/how-to-create-rounded-image-with-border-and-shadow-as-mkannotationview-in-swift)

Comment: It seems I can apply the method in the extenstion if it is to UIView to the annotationView itself.  But the shadow is so subtle I can barely detect it.  But that explains the error.  Will mark correct when permitted. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if my answer was close to an explanation, I’d be grateful if you could give my the correct answer check mark, That helps me continue, thanks